# Get size of a mongo database in a clustered enviroment

Tags: mongodb

As far as I can see there is a command to get the size of the database by using the `db.stats()` command. My question: is there a way to get the total size of all nodes in the cluster for a specific database?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no. You'll have to write a script around `db.stats()`.